# "gcloud init projectname" stopped working. How to check out remote App Engine repo?

Tags: git, google-app-engine

`gcloud init projectname` stopped working and instead now suggests:

> ERROR: (gcloud.init) Invalid value for [projectname]: `gcloud init`
>   has changed and no longer takes a PROJECT argument. Please use `gcloud
>   source repos clone` to clone this project's source repositories.

I had a few attempts but just cannot make this command work.

```
gcloud source repos clone projectname

Cloning into '/Users/boss/gcloudrepositories/projectname'...
fatal: remote error: Repository not found. You may need to create a repository for this project using the Source Code tab at https://console.developers.google.com
```

However there is no feature in the console to *create* a repo.

To add to the confusion, the console **still** advises to use `gcloud auth init projectname`:

[image]

Comment: For now I was able to create a new app engine project locally using GoogleAppEngineLauncher. I made that a local git repo, and then used the instructions in the console to push that repo to the one at app engine. I could then deploy. The commands used were different from before when pushing. Instead of `git push origin master` I have to use `git push --all google` (note to self)

Answer (score 4):

Yeah - there's a bug in the UI there - we'll get that fixed up.  The other  confusing bit here is that the positional argument for `gcloud source repos clone` is the repo name, NOT the project name.  There is a default repo created in your project called 'default'.  The command you're looking for here is:

```
gcloud source repos clone default --project=YOUR_PROJECT_ID
```

This clones the project locally.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, but then second problem come. I'm asked for a username and password, I supposed it's my Google account's but it doesn't work. Probably it's because I'm using 2 factor auth? Anyway it's a pain that Google don't have well document on the changes.

Comment: You need to run a one time command to set up auth.  Is this command working?   git config credential.helper gcloud.sh

Comment: thanks, and I found the instructions here really helps: https://cloud.google.com/tools/cloud-repositories/docs/cloud-repositories-quickstart